# How can I call a kernel written in c from my bootloader

Tags: c, assembly, qemu

I am very beginner in os development
So, here is my bootloader.

**boot.asm**

```
[org 0x7c00]

mov si, STR
call printf

jmp $

printf:
pusha
str_loop:
mov al, [si]
cmp al, 0
jmp print_char
popa
ret

print_char:
mov ah, 0x0e
int 0x10
add si, 1
jmp str_loop

STR: db 'Hello World', 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

Suppose I want to use this C code:

```
void main (void) 
{
   unsigned char* vga = (unsigned char*) 0xb8000;
   vga[0] = 'X'; 
   vga[1] = 0x09; 
   for(;;); 
}
```

As you can see, I am printing Hello World using assembly. But I want to use C to build the kernel and other stuffs. How can I call a kernel which is written in C from my code?

**One more silly question:** I am using QEMU to test the codes. When I have only one file(such as: boot.bin) I can run it like this: `qemu-system-x86_64 boot.bin` from command prompt. But when I will link kernel written in c(such as: kernel.c), how will I run them?

I searched many videos and articles but could not find an answer

**Thanks in Advance!**

Comment: Are you already using C? Starting C with Kernel, is not the easier way.
By the way your .c files should be compile with gcc (or other compiler) this will generate assembly.

Comment: basically, your bootloader loads your kernel into a fixed address in memory and you jump to it

Comment: Ôrel What do you mean by already using C? Suppose I have the simplest example of a c kernel. I just added it in my question

Comment: compile it and link it

Comment: run it the same way you run it now

Comment: old_timer okay, i got it. but how to add c kernel. can u show the code as answer plz?

Comment: Calling a C function from assembly is like calling an assembly subroutine. So what you have to do is call `jmp main` in your bootloader. In order to have the symbol recognized, you have to compile your `kernel.c` to an object file (kernel.o), then link your bootloader with the kernel.o file, and voilà, you get your binary bootloader+kernel.

Comment: A boot loader usually loads the kernel and hands control over to that kernel. I don't see how you can "call the kernel" fro the boot loader.

Comment: Omar I got the point, but can you please show it as an answer. I would just mark it as accepted answer and upvote. This will help me as well as people who will see this threat later.

Comment: https://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones

Comment: Your bootloaded can occupy just 512 bytes, so forget C. On old time (using your bootloader signature), there were a stage 2 to read the more kernel code. In any case you need a .COM file (or a .bin) if such files is generated by a compiler or by an assembler, it doesn't matter. [just your code is still 16bit, and with real mode segments.